# Internet slow after inactivity

Tags: networking, ping, dsl

I am using DSL and noticed that my latency is much higher when I navigate to any website after a period of inactivity. It feels like my ISP is putting my connection to sleep when I'm not constantly using it.

This is hard to prove but I've run ping test and initially see 150ms>> ping and then constant <50ms ping. If I let the ping test run general web browsing feels faster as well.

I realize this is very subjective so I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to quantify this and hopefully avoid the problem.

Comment: Does this happens anytime or only peak hours (mostly at night)?

Comment: Have you set your power options accordingly? Your wireless card could be powering down. Unless you are using ethernet?

Comment: What device are you using, is it a Ethernet or a wireless connection? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1458985/edit) your question to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

While its possible I guess, the Internet does not really work this way because its packet switched. It would seem more likely your router has gone into a lower power mode to save electricity and/or your computer doing something similar.

Its not entirely consistent with your description but this sort of thing cluld also be DNS related (ie DNS removed from cache requiring a new lookup and delaying time to set up a connection), and also things like ARP entries (ie how your computer and the router see each other) being flushed.

Comment: Unfortunately my ISP (Sky) won't let me change my DNS or ARP settings. I tried hacking in a change but the router resets itself when it sees the update. Fortunately, I noticed this within the cancellation window and am switching to a different provider that actually respects Net Neutrality. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DontCallMeLarry, lol what makes you think this has anything to do with net neutrality? 

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It's simple. IP addresses can change so superuser.com might be [151.101.129.69] today and [151.111.111.68] tomorrow. It's difficult (not imposible) for an ISP to know what you are looking at based on the IP. However if the ISP is also acting as the DNS server then they always know when you are trying to access superuser.com. From there they contact the website and ask for month for "faster speeds to their userbase".

Comment: @Dontcallmelarry Your understanding of the way the Internet fits together is warped.  Your assertions are technically possible but highly improbable. The likely reasons for the symptoms you see are entirely different to those you posit, similarly the way connectivity is managed is at a different level.

Comment: @davidgo I'm not making any assertions in my original question or comment. I've only stated what I saw and in the process of troubleshooting realized the shady restrictions set by the ISP. Either way, I've moved to a new ISP with the same hardware and I haven't see any problems since. Go figure.